# TensorFlow ImportError: No module named backports

Tags: python, tensorflow

I remove the tesorflow 0.12rc and install the 1.20.

When I run the process, I got an ImportError

```
ImportError: No module named backports
```

I add backports.weakref package in PyCharm, but I still got above error message.

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The `backports` module is not actually wanted/needed if you're using
Python 3.4+.  There is a pull request to address this:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/11174

But for the time being, a workaround is to just comment out the `import
backports` line in your system's `tf_should_use.py`.